# How to create a new row with conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame equal to the image below. I would like to do the following: create a new row after the end of each numbering in the "Parcela" column. All columns would be repeated, except for the third column (which would be the next numbering), and the last column (which would be the value 120). I tried to think something with the for loop but I still couldn't ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dta.in <- data.frame(Linha = rep(1,11), 
                     Parcela = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,5)), 
                     Arvore = c(74:79,1:5), 
                     Especle = paste0("ABC",1:11), 
                     Nome.vulgar = paste0("CBA",1:11), 
                     CAP.cm. = c(140,230,192,373,161,120,238,175,187,169,258), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

parc.val <- 1;
rowid <- 0
dta.out <- data.frame();


for (i in seq_along(dta.in$Linha)) {
  if (dta.in$Parcela[i] == parc.val) {
    print(paste("Input Row ID:",i))
    dta.out <- rbind(dta.out,dta.in[i,])
    rowid <- rowid+1
    parc.val <- dta.in[i,]$Parcela
    print(paste("Output Row ID:",rowid))
    message("-------------------------")
  } else {
    print(paste("Input Row ID:",i))
    new.row <- c(dta.in[i-1,]$Linha,dta.in[i-1,]$Parcela,dta.in[i-1,]$Arvore+1,dta.in[i-1,]$Especle,dta.in[i-1,]$Nome.vulgar,dta.in[i-1,]$CAP.cm.)
    dta.out <- rbind(dta.out,new.row)
    rowid <- rowid+1
    print(paste("Output Row ID:",rowid))
    dta.out <- rbind(dta.out,dta.in[i,])
    rowid <- rowid+1
    parc.val <- dta.in[i,]$Parcela
    print(paste("Output Row ID:",rowid))
    message("-------------------------")
    }
};
```